# Specify how many rounds and save/present stats, tic tac toe

Tags: python

I have a working tic tac toe game programed in Python, where the computer plays against itself. My program only plays one round of tic tac toe and only presents the winner of that round, or possibly -1 for a tie. I would now like to develop the program so that I can specify how many rounds to play and also save statistics from all these rounds, but I don't know how to do it.

I would like to add the input "How many games do you want to simulate?" before starting the game and the result I would like from this is, for example, if I answer "100" the outcome should be:

Player 1 wins: 15

Player 2 wins: 10

Tie: 75

In other words, all the stats from these 100 games should be presented. Do you have any tips on how I could to this? My current code is:

```
import numpy as np
import random 

# creating an empty board
def create_board(k):
    return np.zeros((k,k), dtype=int)

def possibilities(board): 
 
    lst = [] 
   
    for i in range(len(board)): 
        for j in range(len(board)): 
           
            if board[i][j] == 0: 
                lst.append((i, j)) 
    return(lst)

def random_place(board, player): 
    selection = possibilities(board) 
    current_loc = random.choice(selection)
    board[current_loc] = player 
    return(board) 

def check_row(board, player):
    for x in range(len(board)): 
        win = True
      
        for y in range(len(board)): 
            if board[x, y] != player: 
                win = False
                continue
              
        if win == True: 
            return(win) 
    return(win) 

def check_column(board, player):
      for x in range(len(board)): 
        win = True
      
        for y in range(len(board)): 
            if board[y][x] != player: 
                win = False
                continue
              
        if win == True: 
            return(win) 
      return(win) 

def check_diagonal(board, player):
    win = True
    y = 0
    for x in range(len(board)): 
        if board[x, x] != player: 
            win = False
    if win: 
        return win 
    win = True
    if win: 
        for x in range(len(board)): 
            y = len(board) - 1 - x 
            if board[x, y] != player: 
                win = False
    return win 


def evaluate(board): 
    winner = 0
   
    for player in [1, 2]: 
        if (check_row(board, player) or
            check_column(board,player) or
            check_diagonal(board,player)): 
              
            winner = player 
           
    if np.all(board != 0) and winner == 0: 
        winner = -1
    return winner

def main():

    k = int(input("How big playing surface (3/5/7)? "))

    board, winner, counter = create_board(k), 0, 1

    while winner == 0: 
        for player in [1, 2]: 
            board = random_place(board, player) 
            counter += 1
            winner = evaluate(board) 
            if winner != 0: 
                break
    return(winner)
```

Comment: If you know about `input` and `for x in range(something)` loops, as well as how to use lists, you already have all you need. What are you not sure of how to do?

Comment: Welcome! Sorry, but what you ask isn't our thing around here. Please review [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). "Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a specific question about your implementation. Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation, and is not a way to have research, design or coding work done for you.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @RandomDavis, I am fairly new to Python and have never saved and presented stats from a game before so I didn't know where to start. Should I add one separately loop or construct a new one from the code I already have?

Comment: @Steve thank you! I'm not looking for a complete solution, sorry if it game out that way. I should also have mentioned my attempts to try to solve this. I will review how I asked the question and reformulate myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the query for playing surface out of the main function. Then just make a loop that plays the games and counts the results.

I'd also like to point out that you have a lot of variables with single letter names. You'd be better served replacing those variable names with meaningful names. For example k could be renamed surface or board.

```
def main(k):

#     k = int(input("How big playing surface (3/5/7)? "))

    board, winner, counter = create_board(k), 0, 1

    while winner == 0: 
        for player in [1, 2]: 
            board = random_place(board, player) 
            counter += 1
            winner = evaluate(board) 
            if winner != 0: 
                break
    return(winner)

games=int(input("How many games do you want to simulate?"))
k = int(input("How big playing surface (3/5/7)? "))
player1wins=0
player2wins=0
ties=0
for game in range(games):
    result=main(k)
    if result==-1: ties+=1
    elif result==1: player1wins+=1
    else: player2wins+=1
        
print('Player 1 wins:',player1wins)
print('Player 2 wins:',player2wins)
print('Tie:',ties)
```

Answer (score 0):

You would first need to modify your main() function as to take in the size of the board as a parameter:

```
def main(playing_surface_size):

k = playing_surface_size

board, winner, counter = create_board(k), 0, 1

while winner == 0:
    for player in [1, 2]:
        board = random_place(board, player)
        counter += 1
        winner = evaluate(board)
        if winner != 0:
            break
return(winner)enter code here
```

Then create a function which plays the numbers of games and stores the results in an array

```
def multiple_games(num_games, playing_surface_size):
    count = [0, 0, 0]

    for _ in range(num_games):
        winner = main(playing_surface_size)
        if winner > 0:
            count[winner] += 1
        else:
            count[0] += 1
    return count
```

You would then need to ask the user to input the size of the playing surface and the number of games you want to play

```
playing_surface_size = int(input("How big playing surface (3/5/7)? "))

num_games = int(input("How many games?"))
```

Then call the multiple_games function with the user's inputs

```
games_result = multiple_games(num_games, playing_surface_size)
```

The multiple_games returns an array which contains the number of ties, the number of times the player one won, and the number of times the player 2 won.

You just print them out one after the other:

```
print("Player One Wins:", games_result[1])
print("Player Two Wins:", games_result[2])
print("Tie:", games_result[0])
```